# On what condition is docker image's tag deleted from dockerhub?

Tags: docker, nvidia, dockerhub

I recently found that `docker pull nvidia/cuda:11.1-devel-ubuntu20.04` no longer working although it worked months ago. I noticed this error because my CI's cron-run of docker build started to fail recently. So it's certain that the tag existed before.

In fact, the tag `11.0-devel-ubuntu20.04` disappeared from dockerhub
https://registry.hub.docker.com/v1/repositories/nvidia/cuda/tags

My question is, on what condition tag of docker image is deleted? Or, is this nvidia specific issue?

Comment: In my experience, my images (and their tags) get deleted when and only when I delete them.  So I'd conclude intentional action by nvidia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens when the repository owner deletes the tag. From the GUI, you can select the tags you want to remove and [hit delete](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/image-management/#deleting-a-tagged-image). And there's also an [API to delete images](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/api/latest/#tag/images/operation/PostNamespacesDeleteImages).

As for why nvidia removed their old tags, it could be that they don't want to support the old images anymore. Or maybe there was a known issue and they are forcing users to upgrade. This is entirely up to them and their own policy.